C++ no matching overload function found
I wrote the following code to get a better understand of the template concept and syntax thereof. Imo it should compile, but it causes a compiler error
C(A*)::Find: no matching overload found.
That's all I get, there are no additional messages.
Visual Studio 2022, C++ 20, debug mode (all functions are __cdecl).
I have tried to fix this for the better part of the day, but couldn't. Here's a MRE, it should compile as is (does for me):
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    class A {
    public:
        std::string m_key;
        using KeyType = std::string;

        inline std::string GetKey() const { return m_key; }

        bool operator<(const std::string& key) const {
            return m_key < key;
        }
        bool operator>(const std::string& key) const {
            return m_key > key;
        }
    };

    template<typename DATA_T>
    class B {
    public:
        template<typename KEY_T>
        using tSearchComparator = int(__cdecl*)(const DATA_T*, const typename KEY_T::KeyType&);

        template<typename KEY_T>
        size_t BinSearch(const std::vector<DATA_T>& data, KEY_T key, tSearchComparator<KEY_T> compare, size_t l, size_t r) {
            size_t  m, i;
            do {
                m = (l + r) / 2;
                i = compare(&data[m], key);
                if (i > 0)
                    r = m - 1;
                else if (i < 0)
                    l = m + 1;
                else {
                    // find first record with equal key
                    while ((m > 0) && (compare(&data[m - 1], key) == 0))
                        --m;
                    return m;
                }
            } while (l <= r);
            return -1;
        }
    };

    template<typename DATA_T>
    class C : public B<DATA_T> {
    public:
        std::vector<DATA_T> data;

        template<typename KEY_T>
        inline size_t Find(const KEY_T& key, B<DATA_T>::tSearchComparator<KEY_T> compare, size_t left = 0, size_t right = -1) {
            return this->BinSearch(data, key, compare, left, (right >= 0) ? right : data.size() - 1);
        }
    };


    static int Compare(const A** data, const std::string& key) {
        if ((*data)->m_key < key) return -1;
        if ((*data)->m_key > key) return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    int main() {
        A a1, a2, a3;
        a1.m_key = "apple";
        a2.m_key = "banana";
        a3.m_key = "cherry";

        C<A*> c;
        c.data = { &a1, &a2, &a3 };

        size_t index = c.Find<std::string>("banana", &Compare);

        return 0;
    }

MSVC error log is:
<source>(75): error C2672: 'C<A *>::Find': no matching overloaded function found
<source>(52): note: could be 'size_t C<A *>::Find(const KEY_T &,int (__cdecl *)(const DATA_T *,const KEY_T::KeyType &),size_t,size_t)'
        with
        [
            DATA_T=A *
        ]
<source>(75): note: invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'size_t C<A *>::Find(const KEY_T &,int (__cdecl *)(const DATA_T *,const KEY_T::KeyType &),size_t,size_t)'
        with
        [
            DATA_T=A *
        ]
<source>(27): note: 'B<DATA_T>::tSearchComparator' : Failed to specialize alias template
        with
        [
            DATA_T=A *
        ]
<source>(23): note: 'KeyType': is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'

In case you wondered: I tried to fix this with chatgpt, but it couldn't.

Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the full and complete build log.

Ah, the build log ... I didn't think of that. That was the decisive hint. I was looking for it, but simply didn't find it so far. It's in the IDE's compiler output pane.

https://godbolt.org/z/Yx7dqhT46 don't know if it helps but gcc and clang are reporting many issues. Look into them first perhaps

I was looking for something like the build log, but failed to find it. It's in the IDE's compiler output tab. Now that I can see details about what the compiler sees and expects, I can go on on my own.

For the Find function, KEY_T will be a std::string. This type will be passed on to the tSearchComparator type. And the second argument type is typename KEY_T::KeyType&. Which is the same as std::string::KeyType&. And std::string does not have a KeyType member. Are you supposed to use KEY_T only? Or DATA_T::KeyType?

I was looking for something like the build log, but failed to find it. See pictures https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/968842/output-panel-whats-the-difference-between-build-an
